# How do you cast an integer to a string in Excel's PowerQuery

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have a PowerQuery which pulls back two columns; one a `Number` (an integer), the other `Text` (a string).
I'd like to create a custom column which concatenates these.

It seems this should work: `="(" & ([Value] as text) & ", " & [Description] & ")"`

But this returns error `Expression.Error: We cannot convert the value 1 to type Text.`

NB: This question relates to the PowerQuery editor (i.e. the `M` language); not regular Excel worksheet functions.  The worksheet function to achieve what I'm after would be `=concatenate("(", A2, ", ", B2, ")")`, where A2 is Value and B2 is Description.

Comment: Found It!  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt253385.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Text.From(s)`. It also supports non-number types. It is useful if you're not sure the type of the input (ex: a user-defined cell).

> Returns the text representation of a number, date, time, datetime,
>   datetimezone, logical, duration or binary value. If a value is null,
>   Text.From returns null.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt253343.aspx

Comment: This is the better answer.

Answer (score 6):

Use the `Number.ToText(n)` function.

i.e.  `="(" & Number.ToText([Value]) & ", " & [Description] & ")"`

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt253385.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Note `Number.ToText` only works for numbers. If your argument comes from a user-defined cell which may be pasted into, I find it better to use `Text.From`.